# HTTPS Request (using https nodejs module) of type 'form-data/multipart' not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, multipartform-data

I have the following curl request which is working nicely and as supposed:

> curl --user 'api:MY_API_KEY'
>   https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain/messages --form from='My Name
>   ' --form to=validaddress@domain.com --form
>   subject='Hello 3!' --form text='Testing sending email!'

However I need to craft this request as a valid https request using the standard https module form nodejs, and I tried the following code, however I keep getting 400 (bad request) as response:

```
helpers.sendRequestFormData = function(protocol, port, hostname, method, path, contentType, auth, timeoutSeconds, postData, callback){
   var from = 'My Name <info@mydomain>';
   var to = 'validaddress@domain.com';
   var subject = 'Email test';
   var text = 'Testing sending email';

   var stringPayload = `--${config.mailgun.boundary}
                       \nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="from";
                       \nContent-type: multipart/form-data;
                       \nfrom="${from}";
                       \n--${config.mailgun.boundary}
                       \nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="to";
                       \nContent-type: multipart/form-data;
                       \nto="${to}";
                       \n--${config.mailgun.boundary}
                       \nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="subject";
                       \nContent-type: multipart/form-data;
                       \nsubject="${subject}";
                       \n--${config.mailgun.boundary}
                       \nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="text";
                       \nContent-type: multipart/form-data;
                       \ntext="${text}";
                       \n--${config.mailgun.boundary}\n`;

   // Construct the request
   var requestDetails = {
     'hostname' : hostname,
     'port': port,
     'method' : method,
     'timeout' : timeoutSeconds * 1000,
     'path' : path,
     'headers' : {
       'Authorization': auth,
       'Content-Type': contentType,
       'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload)
     }
   };

   // Instantiate the request object (using either the http or https module)
   var _moduleToUse = protocol == 'http' ? http : https;
   var req = _moduleToUse.request(requestDetails, function(res){

     var responseStatus = res.statusCode;
     console.log(responseStatus);

     res.setEncoding('utf8');
     res.on('data', function(data){

       if(requestStatus == 200){
         callback(false, parsedData);
       }

     });
   });

   // Bind to the error event so it doesn't get thrown
   req.on('error',function(e){
     console.log(e);
     callback(true, {'Error': e});
   });

   // Bind to the timeout event
   req.on('timeout',function(){
     console.log('timeout');
     callback(true, {'Error': 'The request took much time and got timeout.'})
   });

   // Add the payload
   req.write(stringPayload);

   // End the request
   req.end();
 };
```

Can someone please give me some hints, guidance, or tips? I am getting a bit overwhelmed about this, I am sure it might be something simple, been doing trial and error with semi-colons and dashes on the boundary but still didn't got a 200 status response code.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Did your `https` request set `port` to `443`. I did not see any condition for that

Comment: Hi @front_end_dev, yes the port is passed in argument of function

Comment: If you have a 400 error, that means your request is, in some way, wrong. Try to print out both reaquests and check why they are different.

Comment: Hi @MarioSantini that's a good tip yes, I will search out to print out a curl request, maybe -verbose tag or something? I will search thanks!

Comment: The backtick in Javascript is a way to define a template string, so I think you can get rid of the _\n_ characters (and the spaces)...

Comment: There's also no end-boundary (which should look like this: `--${config.mailgun.boundary}--`)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help, not having 400 anymore, now I am having 401 and there is an exception " throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set'): cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" . It's weird, my headers are on the requestDetails object....

Answer (score 1):

I made it working, the current code is the following:

```
helpers.sendRequest = function(protocol, port, hostname, method, path, 

contentType, auth, timeoutSeconds, postData, callback){
   var stringPayload = querystring.stringify(postData);

   // Construct the request
   var requestDetails = {
     'hostname' : hostname,
     'port': port,
     'method' : method,
     'timeout' : timeoutSeconds * 1000,
     'path' : path
   };

   // Instantiate the request object (using either the http or https module)
   var _moduleToUse = protocol == 'http' ? http : https;
   var req = _moduleToUse.request(requestDetails, function(res){
     res.on('data', (d) => {
       if(res.statusCode == 200){
        callback(false);
       }else{
         console.log(res.statusCode);
         callback(true);
       }
     });
   });

   req.setHeader('Authorization', auth);
   req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
   req.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload));

   // Add the payload
   req.write(stringPayload);

   // Bind to the error event so it doesn't get thrown
   req.on('error',function(e){
     console.log(e);
     callback(true, {'Error': e});
   });

   // Bind to the timeout event
   req.on('timeout',function(){
     console.log('timeout');
     callback(true, {'Error': 'The request took much time and got timeout.'})
   });

   // End the request
   req.end();
 };
```

And I call the method like this:

```
genericHelper.sendRequest('https', '443', 'api.mailgun.net', 'POST', '/v3/sandbox0630029a67f24517a9c3e383d2c6098e.mailgun.org/messages',
                    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', ('Basic ' + Buffer.from(('api:'+ config.mailgun.ApiKeyTest)).toString('base64')), 5, emailRequestObject, function(err, data){

// Here I do what I need after sending the http request with success

});
```

I hope it helps someone out, so the problem was the content-type, I had to change it to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and then also the authorization I had to convert to Base64 and include Basic before the pair  in base64.